# Can I install ubuntu studio on pendrive without boot device?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, software-rec

Can I install ubuntu studio on my stick within operating system? Without rebooting my computer to enter installation?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Check [this Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent) which provides several methods.